# How do I chain Promises with interval-promise Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the 'interval-promise' ([github repo here](https://github.com/andyfleming/interval-promise)) module to read a value in a Firebase Realtime DB node for ongoing logins.

The idea is to read a 'status' key from a Realtime DB node which might not exist yet, and to retry until it has a value.

```
const tryGetAuthStatus = (user) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var login_node = user.child(provider);

            if (login_node.exists()) {
                resolve(login_node.val().status)
            }
        })

ref.child(uuid).once('value')     //Returns a promise
    .then((user) => 
        intervalPromise(
            async (iteration, stop) => await tryGetAuthStatus(user),    //Returns a promise
            attempts_pause,
            { iterations: attempts_max, stopOnError: true }
        )
    )
    .then((result) => console.log(result))    //undefined
```

As you can see I'm returning the intervalPromise Promise to continue the promise chain.
When the promise returned from firebaseTryGetAuth resolves, it returns the correct result (e.g. "authorized"), but the last 'then' in the chain gets no result from the returned intervalPromise.

How can I propagate the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval()`'s returned promise does not resolve/pass a long a value from your own async operation. It just does a `resolve()` call to end its own promise

> https://github.com/andyfleming/interval-promise/blob/078528e4096649a56dd2473986d7a1a7eba7909f/src/index.js#L31
>
> ```
> if (currentIteration === settings.iterations || stopRequested) {
>   rootPromiseResolve()
>   return
> }
> ```

Due to this could do a couple things:

1. Save the value of status to an outer scope variable and use it in your last `then()` callback
2. Check the status directly from the function you are passing to `interval()`

---

```
//only use in then() callback
//outside use may result in use before set
let authStatus = null;

let authCheck = (user)=>{
  return async (iteration, stop) => {
    let status = await tryGetAuthStatus(user)
    //set variable for use in then()
    authStatus=status; 

    //or check status now and do so some action
    //instead of in some later then()
    if(status == whatyouwant){ 
      someAction()
      //call stop() since no reason to continue 
      //the async loop
      stop(); 
    }
  };
};

ref.child(uuid).once('value')
    .then((user) => 
        intervalPromise(
            authCheck(user),
            attempts_pause,
            { iterations: attempts_max, stopOnError: true }
        )
    )
    //if you want to go the set outer scope variable route
    .then(() =>{
      if(authStatus == whatever){
        doSomeAction();
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I figured it out by reading the source code better, I had previously misunderstood the way it resolved. Your approaches are valid.